# Trouble with IIS URL Rewrite rules for JS-only front-end

Tags: azure, reactjs, iis, url-rewriting, react-router

I'm building an app with React and react-router and hosting it in IIS on Azure. The app gets it data from a separately hosted WebApi also in IIS on Azure. On the front-end I'm using IIS URL Rewrite rules to redirect HTTP to HTTPS and to redirect anything that's not a physical file to the root of the site. For the most part everything is working great but I have one "virtual" route that I don't want to redirect.

For new users I want to email them a link to https://www.example.com/initialLogin/encryptedtoken. React-router is configured for that route and it proxies the request to the backend where the token is validated. If the token is valid the front-end redirects to a change password page. If that's successful the user is logged in and continues on their merry way.

Locally using webpack-dev-server this flow works exactly as described. In IIS not so much. The simple rewrite rules I've tried give me a 301 and without a rule I just get a 404. I guess that sort of makes sense but is what I'm after possible with my project's combination of technologies?

This is the current version of the rules I have in place. I get a 404 with it I think, because IIS tries to handle the request first and is accurately reporting that the resource doesn't exist.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect HTTP to HTTPS">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
    </rule>
    <rule name="Redirect non-existent paths to root">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/initialLogin/*" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />            
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="/" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Can you share the IIS Url rewrite rule?

Comment: Added rules as requested

Comment: I hope I understand it correctly: you need the "^/initialLogin/*" **rewritten** to the root, possibly "index.html", but having the whole URL intact in the address bar without redirect? Is it the case?

Comment: Actually, I think it's more accurate to say I want that route neither rewritten nor redirected but rather handled by react-router (in the browser). Other "virtual" routes behave that way but only when you're logged in and navigating within the app. It seems I need to find a way to have my app's scripts downloaded after the initialLogin link is plopped in the address bar but before it's submitted.

Comment: After the scripts downloaded it work because the browser intercepts all navigation requests. But with initial you have to tell the browser what content it should load. So I'd add a a rewrite rule for your initial login to /<default_file.ext> and let it handle the rest. Because you have to rewrite, not redirect, "^/initialLogin/*" must hit your react-router, but you have to tell IIS where to find the react-router, hence rewrite to /index.html for example. Then the browser can use react to decide what to do. I can provide the sample in the answer if you want.

Comment: Now I get it ... rewrite not redirect. Kinda what you've been saying all along :) A sample would be very helpful as I'm not clear how I would maintain the token part of the path if I rewrite to /index.html ... or maybe that just gets taken care of for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the rewrite rule I use

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="initialLogin" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^initialLogin/*" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

You can try it [here](http://rewritetest-dave000.azurewebsites.net/initialLogin/mystuff) The javascript is pretty easy I just wrote the windows.location to the body tag, but react-route can pick it up from here.

Comment: Awesome. I'll try it out